# how to use outer table column in inner most subquery where clause in mysql..?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query in which i need to run a sub query which further run a sub query like this :

```
SELECT id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3.abcId = t1.id) t2 
     WHERE /*conditions*/) as total 
FROM t1 WHERE /* condtions */;
```

Now this query throwing error `unknown column t1.id.` Please can anyone tell how to use `t1 table` columns in inner most sub query `where` clause. I have also tried to pass t1 column values through `@variables` like this :

```
SELECT id, @var := t1.id,  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3.abcId = @var) t2 
     WHERE /*conditions*/) as total 
FROM t1 WHERE /* conditions */;
```

But in this case `@var` not getting updated for every row i.e total is returning same value as it get for first row. Please suggest any working solution for this.

Note:- i can't update the flow of query as its calculating something very complex. Above mentioned queries are just an example of original query flow.

Comment: you can not use outer column in subselect

Comment: I already learn that after getting errors. I am asking any alternate solution because i have to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't** do that, SQL engines don't allow the use of an outer query if its more than 1 level away. I can suggest an alternative , avoid one of the sub selects:

```
SELECT t1.id ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t3 
        WHERE t3.abcID = t1.id 
          AND /*conditions */) as total
FROM t1
WHERE /*conditions */
```

Answer (score 0):

The innermost query can be 
Select COLUMN_NAMES from t3,t1 where t3.abcid==t1.id

Comment: It'll not solve my purpose.. will spoil calculations